# How to reduce noticeability of image loading?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a large image header. When the page is refreshed, the header flashes white and then black and then finally the image appears.

I really would like to remove this problem but have not had any success.

Comment: you can load low resolution image and then replace it with the higher resolution image once it is loaded

Comment: @AmericanSlime while trying out the solution proposed below, it removed the image header.

Comment: Link to the website: 
https://shop-gohrvst.myshopify.com/

Comment: @ItayGrudev could you please delete the above comment? It is not relevant to the question and could have negative SEO implications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it would be a good idea to have the background of the container element for the image be black (so that during the time when the image isn't being shown at least you won't see white), then you can apply a default CSS rule that the image is hidden by default. Then, using the `load` event, you can remove that CSS:

```js
// Get reference to the image element
var img = document.querySelector("#img");

// Set up an event handler for when the image is fully loaded that removes
// the hidden class, thus revealing the image:
img.addEventListener("load", function(){
  img.classList.remove("hidden");
});
```

```css
/* Set the size of the container to the size of the image and 
   set its background color to black.                        */
#container {
  height:2000px;
  width:2000px;
  background-color:#000;
}

.hidden { visibility:hidden; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <img src="http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hvi/uploads/image_file/image_attachment/29911/STSCI-H-p1706a-m2000x2000.png" id="img" class="hidden">
</div>
```

Comment: Also to state the obvious, try to see if you can compress the image more or otherwise reduce the files use so it loads quicker.

Comment: @dman2306 That's surely a good idea, but still won't solve the issue is multiple refreshes happen very quickly.

Comment: I tried to test this out, however it left the image header completely blank instead.

Comment: @SpencerM. You must not have included my example properly. As you'll see from my snippet, the code works just fine.

Comment: @ScottMarcus all I had to do was give the class "hidden" and id "img" to the div and it should have worked right?

Comment: @SpencerM. No. That is why it disappeared and didn't come back. You must also add the JavaScript which causes the image to come back after it's been fully downloaded. You also need to add CSS that styles the image container to have a black background as I've shown.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yes sorry I thought it was implied that I also added the javascript function. However it still didn't work for me.

Comment: @SpencerM. As I said, you have something else going on because this code wouldn't cause the image to disappear indefinitely.Have you checked your browser's developer console for errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of the fadeIn animation on the '.slick-initialized .hero__image' css.

```
.slick-initialized .hero__image{opacity:1;-webkit-animation:fadeIn 1s cubic-bezier(0.44, 0.13, 0.48, 0.87);-moz-animation:fadeIn 1s cubic-bezier(0.44, 0.13, 0.48, 0.87);-o-animation:fadeIn 1s cubic-bezier(0.44, 0.13, 0.48, 0.87);animation:fadeIn 1s cubic-bezier(0.44, 0.13, 0.48, 0.87)}
```